# VBA: When no value is found, first row is deleted

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that deletes every row that doesn't contain a key string (in this case "2550"). The issue is, if I run the script twice by mistake, it will delete the top row in the worksheet.

See the code below:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

lastRow = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("L1:L" & lastRow)

With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*2550*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

I thought that if there was no row with that key, the AutoFilter would show nothing and therefore nothing should be deleted, but it appears that that is not the case. Could anyone explain why that may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use the Max function in your last row declaration.  Something like:

```
lastRow = Application.Max(2,ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Allows you to skip some nesting and IF statements.

Answer (score 1):

Put in a test..

```
lastRow = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If lastRow = 1 Then
  Set rng = ws.Range("L1:L" & lastRow)

  With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*2550*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
  End With

  ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
```

If lastRow returns the top row, it won't do the rest.